# is there any neo4j apoc procdecure for shortestpath with predicate(filter)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have checked the below latest neo4j apoc procedures and observed that there is no predicate option to find the shortest path between two nodes.

Can somebody help is there any apoc procedures with predicates(filters)

```
      apoc.algo.dijkstra(startNode, endNode, 'KNOWS|<WORKS_WITH|IS_MANAGER_OF>', 'distance') YIELD path, weight

      apoc.algo.dijkstraWithDefaultWeight(startNode, endNode, 'KNOWS|<WORKS_WITH|IS_MANAGER_OF>', 'distance', 10) YIELD path, weight

      apoc.algo.aStar(startNode, endNode, 'KNOWS|<WORKS_WITH|IS_MANAGER_OF>', 'distance','lat','lon') YIELD path, weight

      apoc.algo.aStar(startNode, endNode, 'KNOWS|<WORKS_WITH|IS_MANAGER_OF>', {weight:'dist',default:10, x:'lon',y:'lat'}) YIELD path, weight

      apoc.algo.allSimplePaths(startNode, endNode, 'KNOWS|<WORKS_WITH|IS_MANAGER_OF>', 5) YIELD path, weight
```

Comment: You can do this with pure Cypher as of Neo4j 3.0.

Comment: Thanks nicole for your reply.But we dont want to use pure cypher as it is very difficult to construct dynamic query. As we need dynamic query, our requirement is to use either apoc procedure or pure neo4j java api.It will be helpful if you can be give me the suggestions what neo4j api to use?